# Can't get % widths to work on a div table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I am making a daily planner view for a website and I am having trouble formatting it. Here is the code I have below:

**CSS**

```
.responsive-calendar .controls {
    color: #666;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: "Open Sans",Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
}

.responsive-calendar .controls a {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.responsive-calendar .controls h4 {
    display: inline;
}

.responsive-calendar .day-headers, .responsive-calendar .days, .responsive-calendar .timeslots {
    font-size: 0;
}

.responsive-calendar .header {
    background-color: #f3f2f2 !important;
    box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255) inset;
    color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 18px;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor:default !important;
}

/* Daily Planner CSS */
.responsive-calendar .timeslot {
    height:auto;
    display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    flex-flow: row column;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row column;
}

.responsive-calendar .hour {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
    border:1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    -webkit-flex:1 1 100%;
}

.responsive-calendar .appts {
    height:auto;
    display:flex;
    display:-webkit-flex;
    width: 900%;
    flex-flow: row column;
    -webkit-flex-flow: row column;
}

.responsive-calendar .appt {
    background-color:#CCC;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
    border:1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    width: 90%;
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    -webkit-flex:1 1 100%;
}

.responsive-calendar .appt a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 10px;
    border:1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
    text-align: center;
    flex: 1 1 100%;
    -webkit-flex:1 1 100%;
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection:hover {
    background-color: rgb(227, 235, 253);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection a {
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 3% 0 3% 0;
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection a:hover {
    /* background-color: #eee; */
    text-decoration: none;
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection.header {
    border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection.active {
    background-color: rgb(209, 206, 224);
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection.active:hover {
    background-color: rgb(227, 235, 253);
}

.responsive-calendar .timesection.not-current {
    background-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
    cursor:default;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="responsive-calendar">
    <div class="controls">
        <img src="images/left_16.png" />
        <?php echo date("M d, Y", mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,$cDay,$cYear)); ?>
        <img src="images/right_16.png" />
        <a style="padding-left:15px;">Today</a>
        <a style="padding-left:15px;">Monthly View</a>
    </div>
    <div class="day-headers">
        <div class="hour header"><strong>Times</strong></div>
        <div class="appt header"><strong>Appointments</strong></div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeslots">
        <div class="timeslot">
            <div class="timesection hour">10:00am</div>
            <div class="timesection appt">Test 1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeslot">
            <div class="timesection hour">11:00am</div>
            <div class="timesection appt">Test 2</div>
            <div class="timesection appt">Test 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeslot">
            <div class="timesection hour">12:00pm</div>
            <div class="appts">
                <div class="timesection appt">Hack Result 1</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="timeslot">
            <div class="timesection hour">12:00pm</div>
            <div class="appts">
                <div class="timesection appt">Hack Result 2</div>
                <div class="timesection appt">Hack Result 3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davellan/obo1ur90/).

So in the demo, what I want is the hacked result (the last 2 rows of `div` table).

I am using bootstrap 3.3.4, and the attached CSS to style the page. I am not sure why I can't get the header divs to line up properly by the percentages (10%, 90%), but then the div's below don't want to match up below.

In the hacked result, I just added another class, appts, and inflated that to 900% and it gets close the what I wanted. But I want this done properly, and to understand why this isn't working as I hoped.

What I want is all the times to be 10% of the available width, and then the appts to occupy 90% of the available width. If there is more than one .appt, then they divide the 90% width evenly.

Comment: Just out of interest, is there any reason why you aren't using an actual `table` for this information (it is tabular data)?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes - I want this to look good on mobiles and scale well. I have done this with a table and it just doesn't scale right, or at least I couldn't make it scale well.

Comment: @DavidAvellan Getting this to work on mobile and scaling correctly should actually be *easier* with tables than with divs, imo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```css
.responsive-calendar .controls {
  color: #666;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
}
.responsive-calendar .controls a {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.responsive-calendar .day-headers,
.responsive-calendar .days,
.responsive-calendar .timeslots {
  font-size: 0;
}
.responsive-calendar .header {
  background-color: #f3f2f2 !important;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px 0px rgb(255, 255, 255) inset;
  color: rgb(102, 102, 102);
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 18px;
  padding: 10px 0px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: default !important;
}
.responsive-calendar .hour {
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 10%;
  float: left;
}
.responsive-calendar .appts {
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
}
.responsive-calendar .appt {
  background-color: #CCC;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  text-align: center;
}
.responsive-calendar .appt a {
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(221, 221, 221);
  text-align: center;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  -webkit-flex: 1 1 100%;
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection:hover {
  background-color: rgb(227, 235, 253);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection a {
  color: #000000;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 3% 0 3% 0;
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection.header {
  border-bottom: 1px gray solid;
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection.active {
  background-color: rgb(209, 206, 224);
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection.active:hover {
  background-color: rgb(227, 235, 253);
}
.responsive-calendar .timesection.not-current {
  background-color: rgb(205, 205, 205);
  cursor: default;
}
.appt {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="responsive-calendar">
  <div class="controls">
    <img src="images/left_16.png" />
    <?php echo date( "M d, Y", mktime(0,0,0,$cMonth,$cDay,$cYear)); ?>
    <img src="images/right_16.png" /> <a style="padding-left:15px;">Today</a>
    <a style="padding-left:15px;">Monthly View</a>

  </div>
  <div class="day-headers">
    <div class="hour header"><strong>Times</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="appt header"><strong>Appointments</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="timeslots">
    <div class="timeslot">
      <div class="timesection hour">10:00am</div>
      <div class="appts">

        <div class="timesection appt">Test 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeslot">
      <div class="timesection hour">11:00am</div>
      <div class="appts">
        <div class="timesection appt ">Test 2</div>
        <div class="timesection appt  ">Test 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeslot">
      <div class="timesection hour">12:00pm</div>
      <div class="appts">
        <div class="timesection appt">Hack Result 1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeslot">
      <div class="timesection hour">12:00pm</div>
      <div class="appts">
        <div class="timesection appt">Hack Result 2</div>
        <div class="timesection appt">Hack Result 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I've done:

**HTML**:

- Wrapped the elements which have `.timesection .appt` with a `div.appts`.

**CSS**:

- Completely removed `.responsive-calendar .timeslot` css.
- Removed `display:inline-block;`, `position:relative;` and added `float:left;` to `.responsive-calendar .hour`.
- Removed  `display:-webkit-flex;`, `width: 900%;`, `flex-flow: row column;`, `-webkit-flex-flow: row column;` from `.responsive-calendar .appts`.
- Removed `flex`, `width`, `position` and `display` from `.responsive-calendar .appt`.
- At last added `.appt` a `max-width: 100%;`

Also find an **[example pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOzVVq)**.

Comment: You need to include `bootstrap.min.css` somewhere in your code snippet.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it is now included.

Comment: Ok, so this is a step in the right direction, but there is still one problem. If the appt div is taller (add a <br> or two), the appt div and appts div stretches accordingly, but the hour div doesn't. I would like them to all scale together.

Here is an example of what I mean using your new code:

https://jsfiddle.net/davellan/ndv51kqz/

Comment: You could add another class lets call it `.custom` on the `.timesection .hour` and you can alter the `line-height` property from there. Otherwise you will need to use jquery or something to get the value foreach of the `.timesection .appt` and apply the height to `.timesection .hour`.

Comment: Hmm, weird. On my jsFiddle it didn't pop up right, but maybe that is just a glitch. I will try it on my live page. https://jsfiddle.net/davellan/ndv51kqz/2/

Comment: Updated my live page and it worked. Not sure why the jsFiddle looks a little funny. Thank you @cchacholiades!